# Spring validation returns long error messages, not just the customized message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator

Spring validation returns long error message instead of the customized once.

This is the section of code in the dto.

```
public class RequestDto implements Serializable {
    @NotNull(message="{id.required}")
    private Long id;

}
```

In controller added the @Valid for input.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ApiPath.PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/xml",
            "application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody ResultDecorator saveRequest(
            @Valid @RequestBody RequestDto msaDisabScreenRequestDto) throws Exception {

}
```

API returns the following error.

```
<message>Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public om.gov.moh.msa.framework.resolver.ResultDecorator om.controller.MaController.saveRequest(om..dto.RequestDto) throws java.lang.Exception, with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'requestDto' on field 'id': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.requestDto.id,NotNull.id,NotNull.java.lang.Long,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [requestDto.id,id]; arguments []; default message [civilId]]; **default message [ID is required.]]** </message>
```

Here the custom message is present at the end. (**default message [ID is required.**)

Using Controller advice for global exception and I'm overriding handleMethodArgumentNotValid. How can I return only the custom message here?

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {



   /**
    * Spring validation related exception
    */
   @Override
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
           MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
           HttpHeaders headers,
           HttpStatus status,
           WebRequest request) {

       ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
       apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
       return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get default/custom message like `result.getFieldError("yourFieldName").getDefaultMessage()`

You can catch error messages either through controller method which should look like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = ApiPath.PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/xml", "application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody ResultDecorator saveRequest(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDto msaDisabScreenRequestDto, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            String errorMessage = result.getFieldError("yourFieldName").getDefaultMessage();
        }
    }
```

Or through Global Exception handler

### Updated

```
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {



       /**
        * Spring validation related exception
        */
       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
               MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
               HttpHeaders headers,
               HttpStatus status,
               WebRequest request) {

           //New Code
           BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
           String errorMessage = result.getFieldError("yourFieldName").getDefaultMessage();
//---------------
           ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
           apiError.setMessage(errorMessage);
           return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
       }
    }
```

Comment: `result.getFieldError("...")` should be `bindingResult.getFieldError(...)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Afridi,
Created a string buffer and added all the error messages into that.

```
   /**
    * Spring validation related exception
    */
   @Override
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
           MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
           HttpHeaders headers,
           HttpStatus status,
           WebRequest request) {

       final StringBuffer errors = new StringBuffer();
       ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
       for (final FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
           errors.append("\n");
           errors.append(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
       }
       apiError.setMessage(errors.toString());
       return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

As Afridi said in `@ControllerAdvice` can do this also:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ResponseBody
public Result methodArgumentNotValidExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response, MethodArgumentNotValidException e) throws IOException {
    String message = e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage();

    // todo return to your custom result
}
```

There are two point :

- Exception class is `MethodArgumentNotValidException`
- The first Error `getDefaultMessage()` can get your custom message in `Annotation`

Answer (score 1):

In WebFlux :

Handle `WebExchangeBindException` for customising the default error message of `@Valid`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> handleException(WebExchangeBindException e) {
        var errors = e.getBindingResult()
                .getAllErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }

}
```

Reference : https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-webflux-validation/