# Spring Boot - Required @RequestBody class fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following API definition:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(path = "/configureSection")
public ResponseEntity<ResultData> configureSegment(@RequestParam() String Section,
                                                       @RequestBody SectionConfig sectionConfig);
```

```
public class SegmentConfig {
    @JsonProperty(value = "txConfig", required = true)
    TelemetryConfig telemetryConfig;
    @JsonProperty(value = "rxConfig")
    ExternalConfig externalConfig;
}
```

I defined txConfig is required attribute (which is class), but when sending empty JSON (`{}`) spring boot still runs the API while I expect it to return an error that parameter tsConfig was not set.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Edit: Using @Valid and @NotNull solved it, but the error returned is too informative, any way to fix it?

```
 {
    "timestamp": 1588753367913,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.segmentConfig.telemetryConfig",
                "NotNull.telemetryConfig",
                "NotNull.services.TelemetryConfig",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "segmentConfig.telemetryConfig",
                        "telemetryConfig"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "telemetryConfig",
                    "code": "telemetryConfig"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "Please provide a valid txConfig",
            "objectName": "segmentConfig",
            "field": "telemetryConfig",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/mypath"
}`
```

Comment: try adding `@Valid` annotation on `telemetryConfig` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use @Valid and @NotNull annotation to validate as below :-**

```
@ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(path = "/configureSection")
    public ResponseEntity<ResultData> configureSegment(@RequestParam() String Section,
                                                       @RequestBody @Valid SectionConfig sectionConfig
                                                        )  {

public class SegmentConfig {

    @JsonProperty(value="txConfig", required = true)
    @NotNull(message="Please provide a valid txConfig")
    TelemetryConfig telemetryConfig;
    @JsonProperty(value="rxConfig")
    ExternalConfig externalConfig;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The errorr is a little bit strange - actually very big and too informative - any way to change it? Added the code to the question

Comment: @TheUnreal Are you handle  `MethodArgumentNotValidException` in your exception handler?

Comment: @Eklavya No. And also not sure what you mean I can do. Any ref?

Comment: @TheUnreal See the Update part of accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737381/spring-validation-returns-long-error-messages-not-just-the-customized-message